# Как сохранить данные в txt.файл по нажатию кнопки asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, файлы, asp.net-mvc

Допустим я хочу добавить книгу\товар\пользователя без разницы что ,у меня есть форма с полями для ввода ,и после того как я заполнил поля ,я хочу по нажатию кнопки сохранить данные в txt.файл. Я искал в интернете ответ на данный вопрос ,но конкретно ничего не нашел ,может вы сможете что-то посоветовать ? Если вопрос не совсем понятен и нужно больше информации ,пишите - я добавлю инфу .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Json.Net для сериализации формы, полученной от пользователя.
Используйте System.IO.File для сохранения файла. Пользуйтесь асинхронными версиями методов, если это возможно

Answer (score -1):

Создай форму с кнопкой:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="book_name" placeholder="book name">
  <input type="text" name="book_describe" placeholder="describe your book">
  <button name="success">Send</button>
</form>
```

теперь обработай в php коде:

```
if(isset($_POST['success'])){
  $book_name = $_POST['book_name'];
  $book_describe = $_POST['book_describe'];
```

и код записи в файл(почитай о нем больше):

```
 $file = fopen("адрес файла например: logs/text.txt", "a+t");
 fwrite($file, "$book_name\n$book_describe");
 fclose($file);
}
```

все) код создает, или, если такой файл есть - записывает в него текст, введенный в форму)

Comment: Ваш ответ не на требуемом языке программирования

Comment: упппс( сори( не надо - ставить( не заметил(

Comment: Я поставил минус, не могу его отменить, пока вы не отредактируете ответ.